# page.evaluate returning null values but browser console returning correct values

Tags: javascript, puppeteer

I am using Puppeteer for a web scraping application. Page.evaluate function is returning null values. But the same function in the browser console returns the right values.

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');
let scrape = async () => {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch({headless:false});
  const page = await browser.newPage();
  var ticker = 'DIS';
  var my_url = 'https://seekingalpha.com/symbol/'  + ticker + '/momentum/moving-averages'; 
  await page.setUserAgent('Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:66.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/66.0');
  await page.goto(my_url);


  page.on('console', msg => console.log('PAGE LOG:', msg.text()));
  const result = await page.evaluate(() => {
    const elements = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('table tr td'));
    let links = elements.map(element => {
        return element.href
    })
    console.log(links, 'inside page.evaluate');
    return links;
  });
    browser.close();
    return result;
};  


scrape().then((value) => {
  console.log(value); // Success!
```

Getting the following results....

```
PAGE LOG: JSHandle@array inside page.evaluate
[ null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null ]
```

in the browser console, I get....

```
document.querySelectorAll('table tr td')
NodeList(10) [ td.left.left-text, td.middle.center-text, td.middle.center-text, td.middle.center-text, td.right.center-text, td.left.left-text, td.middle.center-text.red, td.middle.center-text.green, td.middle.center-text.green, td.right.center-text.green ]
```

Would appreciate any help...

With Thomas suggestion, I was able to make the following adjustments and it works now...

```
sma[0] = await page.$eval('table tr:nth-child(2) td:nth-child(2)', el => {return el.innerHTML });
  sma[1] = await page.$eval('table tr:nth-child(2) td:nth-child(3)', el => {return el.innerHTML });
  sma[2] = await page.$eval('table tr:nth-child(2) td:nth-child(4)', el => {return el.innerHTML });
  sma[3] = await page.$eval('table tr:nth-child(2) td:nth-child(5)', el => {return el.innerHTML });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `console.log(links, 'inside page.evaluate')` is executing inside the browser runtime. Any data logged or send from the browser to the Node.js environment needs to be serializable (see the [docs](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/v1.15.0/docs/api.md#pageevaluatepagefunction-args)), which is not the case for DOM elements. Therefore `null` is shown instead.

To query the elements, you could use the function [page.$$(selector)](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/v1.15.0/docs/api.md#pageselector-1). Example:

```js
const tds = await page.$$('table tr td');
```

The code inside the browser is working fine though. I think your actual problem is that your code is querying the `td` elements and then trying to map the `td` elements to their `href` value. You probably want to iterate over `a` elements instead I'm assuming. So probably your selector should be `'table tr td a'` instead.